# Can Jconsole help in debugging Lucene issue?

Tags: java, lucene, lucene.net, jconsole

We are facing JVM crashed (Full crash logs - http://pastebin.com/845LU9iK )which results in Jboss going down. Jboss version is EAP 6.3 and we have Java jdk1.7.0_72 installed.From the crash logs we observed that JVM is crashing on LUCENE merge thrread always..and all the elasticsearched thread are blocked. For monitering thread we connected through JCONSOLE but there is wind range of category in thread section ..Is there a way we can moniter Lucene merge threads from JCONSOLE ?
JVM crash log look like :

```
A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  Internal Error (os_windows_x86.cpp:143), pid=3088, tid=1144
#  guarantee(result == EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_EXECUTION) failed: Unexpected result from topLevelExceptionFilter
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_72-b14) (build 1.7.0_72-b14)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.72-b04 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Failed to write core dump. Call to MiniDumpWriteDump() failed
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00000000d1d99000):  JavaThread "Lucene Merge Thread #0" daemon [_thread_in_Java, id=1144, stack(0x00000000f6a00000,0x00000000f6b00000)]

Stack: [0x00000000f6a00000,0x00000000f6b00000]
[error occurred during error reporting (printing stack bounds), id 0xc0000005]


[error occurred during error reporting (printing native stack), id 0xc0000005]
```

Thanks,
Rahul

Comment: Please put the relavant section of the logs in the question. External links are prone to break, especially when you can't even be bothered to put the URL in correctly

Comment: Much improved. Sorry, I can't help, but down vote reverted.

Comment: Can someone please help me knowing if we can use JCONSOLE for trouble shooting issue with LUcene thread ? If yeas how to do that ?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't go that route. Assuming you aren't calling native code, which it doesn't look like since that is deep inside Lucene code, crashes like that is a Java bug. If you can easily recreate it, I would try with a newer build of Java, or with Java8. You also have a lot of experimental (and potentially dangerous) options set in your JVM that you may want to try turning off.

Comment: The issue is occuring on prod and we are still not aware what is the trigger  for the issue so reproducing is still a question. Although there is pattern in the JVM Crash that it happen mostly (90/100 times) on Monday. Is there any other way possible through which we can moniter what is happening with Lucene ? are there any logs which I can moniter  ?

Comment: You can add logging to your code that is calling Lucene. Is the concurrent merge scheduler set to create a large # of threads? At the end of the day, this really is almost definitely a JVM bug, and your options will be limited.

Comment: Here I get an idea ..let me check with how can we add logging to the code ...let me check on it.

Comment: We have A BPM tool ...and jboss is serving as an application server ..The BPM tool is using Lucene/ elastic search thread ..I am not sure if we can modify them to start writinglogs